# Changing the states of widgets by clicking button

Tags: android

am new to android , totally there are 5 images....

Two main buttons are **up and down arrows** (Image buttons)... and **three images** (Image Buttons)...
  If i click **down** arrow, it should focus the image buttons one by one and if i click **up** arrow, vice versa...   Thanks in advance...

```
 <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/ib_movies"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/img_trailer" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/ib_movies"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/img_trailer" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/ib_movies"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/img_trailer" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/iv_up_arrow"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/up_arrow" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/iv_down_arrow"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/down_arrow" />
```

Comment: What do you mean it should focus them?

Comment: Drew Stauft : It should change the background state of that three images when i click  up and down arrow button.. got ??